# Can Shizuku's vacuum cleaner suck nuclear weapons?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Can Shizuku, who is the 8th member of the Phantom Troupe use her Nen ability to absorb a detonated or/and a non-detonated nuclear weapon?

Can it suck the radiation caused by such weapons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Hunter X Hunter [Wiki](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Shizuku), Shizuku's vacuum (Blinky) can inhale nuclear weapon because it is not a living object, but if it is a conjured object Blinky can't inhale it.

Comment: The wiki is not canon but you are right.  These are the only known restrictions so far stated to her power.